# Dynamic shading (piano)

Tags: piano

I've just finished "The Art of Piano Playing" by George Kochevitsky. In it, 'dynamic shading' is referenced a number of times. Here is an example from the text:

p.50: "Before playing a composition [the pianist] has to become familiar with its form, harmonic and polyphonic structure, metrical-rhythmic relationships, melodic design, phrasing, articulation, quality of desired sonority and dynamic shading."

I understand all the other terms, but what exactly is meant by 'dynamic shading' in the context of piano playing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the word "shading" here is not used in relationship to a shadow, but instead in terms of color. (A "shade" can mean either a specific color or a device to block out the sun or a bright light).

So "dynamic shading" almost certainly means the color added to a piece through the use of dynamics (i.e., loudness or softness).

Pretty much any Beethoven piano work is a good example for the use of dynamics in a piano composition. Before playing an Beethoven piano work, it would be a good idea to get a sense of how Beethoven intends the dynamics to flow through the piece and what the intended effect of each dynamic mark is. Beethoven's piano work would be a good place to start a study in piano dynamics, because most of his dynamics are fairly clear-cut and dramatic.

Comment: I see, so the analogy implied by the term 'shading' is that of varying intensity or tone on a note-by-note or phrase-by-phrase basis?

Comment: @MattsonT The phrase "dynamic shading" is just a fancy way of saying "dynamics". That's all. The dynamics in a piece are important **both** from note to note **and** from phrase to phrase.

Comment: @MattsonT If my answer was helpful, then you could click the up arrow to the left above the **0** to indicate it helped you. If you're still confused about it, feel free to add more comments or edit more details in your question and maybe someone else will understand better than I do.

Comment: The answer was very helpful. However, as this is my first question on stackexchange, I don't have the 'reputation' yet for my vote to be recorded. I'll come back and mark it as helpful as soon as I can. Thanks again.

Comment: @mattson I had no idea rep was required to vote up. No worries. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fairly common cheat.  Sing the song "Mary Had A Little Lamb." As the notes go low, sing softer, as they go high, sing louder.

No two notes should be exactly the same.  They must go somewhere dynamically.  Even a singer who sustains a note, does something with it by either modifying the vowel, their palate or tongue, or dynamic. The challenge with the piano is that it only decays so it is imperative that the notes before always go somewhere dynamically.

Just as a pianist uses entasis with the timing of notes, they can do much the same with the dynamics.

Consider the sing-songy cadence of a barrister at law.  Every word comes from somewhere and goes somewhere and the words that he accents or slows down on are the words we focus on. So must each note of the piano score.

Try this exercise.  Play *AND* sing this sentence at the piano using just one note.  Accent or rise and fall to the capitalized word in each sentence:
*I* want to kiss you.
I WANT to kiss you.
I want to KISS you. 
I want to kiss YOU.

See how the sentence moves to a direction and the accent even changes the meaning.  Do the same with your piano playing.